# Adding a subsection to a table [Angular]

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I'm trying to sections to my table. The aim is to create a row similar to the header row of the table where this information will live.

I have already tried adding a separate header as an ng container.
I'm trying to avoid using a div and styling it to make it look similar to a table header.
I'd prefer for the "title" of the table to be a part of the table HTML.

Thanks!

Comment: What constitutes 'useful information'? Are you trying to do a literal dump of the underlying object?

Comment: Not an object dump. Useful information was merely meant as a placeholder for a couple word descriptor of what the table contains. It isn't important to the problem at hand except for the fact that it will just be a couple of static/hardcoded words in Length